# Event Triggered Toast Notification UWP

Tags: wpf, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

Idea:I am automating wifi login for a particular network where user have to enter credentials by poping a toast notification like alarm app but instead of snooze or dismiss button there would be login or logout.
Issue:How to trigger toast notification immediately when the user connect to a particular wifi network?

[image: Toast]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a Background Task which is getting triggered by a System Event - in your case the `NetworkStateChanged` trigger.

- Here are a list of  available triggers:

  [SystemTriggerType Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br224839)
- And here is a quick introduction how to respond to such a system
  event:

  [Respond To System Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/respond-to-system-events-with-background-tasks)

You can then check if you want to show the toast by using `Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile()`

Look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/32846558/5111904 or look up the documentation of the NetworkInformation class for further information.